# proguard as ant task

Tags: java, ant, proguard

I actually have two related questions:

1. Can predefined constants be expanded in the task declarations as `<injar  file="${build}/myjar.jar" />`?
2. How can I reuse the classpath definition in proguard? What I am trying to achieve is not to specify the whole set of required libraries. They are quite a lot and they are already included in ant's classpath with specific id.

Thanks a lot.

Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can use Ant variables. However from my point of view it is easier to write all command-line options into the body of the proguard task:

```
<taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="lib/proguard.jar" />
<proguard>
    -libraryjars "${java.home}/lib/rt.jar"
    -injars     "${jar.name}"
    -outjars    build/temp.jar
    -keep class test.Main { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }
    -dontwarn
    -dontoptimize 
    -dontobfuscate
</proguard>
```

For converting a defined Class path to a string that can be included into the proguard definition you can use the Ant task [PathConvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html). The first example on the linked page should be what you need.

**Update:** How to get the quotes around the path entries has been answered here: [How to properly quote a path in an ant task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955831/how-to-properly-quote-a-path-in-an-ant-task)

Comment: PathConvert doesn't add quotes around file names with spaces, as expected by ProGuard (at least up to version 4.6), so regular XML elements might be safer for path specifications. Other options are indeed more compact and more readable in embedded ProGuard-style.

Comment: I added a link in my answer to a question describing the solution on the quote problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, yes. Expansion of variables like that in a build file is a feature of Ant. It will work with any tasks you use.